# jQuery not capturing click event following trigger call on HTML radio button

Tags: javascript, jquery, onclick, radio-button, eventtrigger

I have a very strange issue with jQuery where I am triggering a click on a radio button but it is not firing completely and is not being captured by an `on` click function, however a similar call to jQuery `trigger` *is* being captured.

In the following jQuery I am selecting a `<div>` and using `find` to search for the suitable content.

```
var prev_chosen_d_option = $('#d_options_table .d_option_row[data-option-id="' + d_option_for_jq + '"]');

// this works, and the on click is captured
prev_chosen_d_option.find('.hover_target').trigger("click", true);

// this selects the radio button, but DOES NOT fire the on click function seen below    
prev_chosen_d_option.find('#d_standard_use_b_as_s_no').trigger("click", true);
```

These are my radio buttons:

```
<input type="radio" value="yes" id="d_standard_use_b_as_s_yes" name="d_standard_use_b_as_s">

<input type="radio" value="no" id="d_standard_use_b_as_s_no" name="d_standard_use_b_as_s">

$("#d_options_table .d_option_row .hover_target").on("click", function(e, isFirstLoad) {
   // it comes in here fine!
});

$('input[name=d_standard_use_b_as_s], input[name=d_next_day_use_b_as_s], #del_standard_use_b_as_s_no').on("click", function(e, isFirstLoad) {
 // it DOESN'T come in here
});
```

I can't see how jQuery is able to select the radio button and successfully check it, but the `on` method doesn't pick it up as a click...especially when I have a very similar setup running in close proximity in the code.

I know for sure that the radio buttons are within the selector as I can dump it out to the console with a `console.log`. Interestingly, when I dump out the events attached to it to the console I get `undefined` from this **after** the `trigger`:

```
console.log(prev_chosen_d_option.find("#_standard_use_b_as_s_no").data('events'));
```

(I am using jQuery 1.7.2 and testing in FF).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason for this not working was simply I had the click handler below where I was actually triggering the click in the code.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of

```
    $('input[name=del_standard_use_b_as_s], input[name=del_next_day_use_b_as_s], #del_standard_use_b_as_s_no').on('click', function(e) {
//
    });
```

Try :

```
$(document).on('click', 'input[name=del_standard_use_b_as_s], input[name=del_next_day_use_b_as_s], #del_standard_use_b_as_s_no', function(e) {
 // 
});
```

Comment: No, sadly this has no effect. It captures the normal click (as does the original code), but it does not capture the `trigger` click. Would the syntax have an effect here do you think?

Comment: And $(prev_chosen_d_option).find('#d_standard_use_b_as_s_no')
instead of prev_chosen_d_option.find('#d_standard_use_b_as_s_no')
? 
And is it normal that you have #d_standard_use_b_as_s_no and not 
#del_standard_use_b_as_s_no ?

Comment: In the second on(), you forgot the isFirstLoad argument

Comment: Thanks, but I had intentionally left that out (as it is unused). I've updated my question to keep it in line though. For the life of me I cannot see what is wrong with this code.

Comment: Yes, it's strange.
What if you try with click(), like in jQuery documentation ?

$("p").click( function (event, isFirstLoad) {

} );

$("p").trigger("click", true);

Comment: Yes, I tried `click`. No luck :( What am I missing? (Must be something silly).

Comment: Please provide a fiddle with all concerned code.
It might be something else, because everything here looks fine to me.

Comment: Well, it seems to work in the jsFiddle - http://jsfiddle.net/crmpicco/bw6NA/3/ :-/

Comment: Oh dear, it looks like the reason for this not working was simply I had the `click` handler _below_ where I was actually triggering the click in the code. <facepalm>